# Webcamjs: Live images are not getting captured properly in safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, html5-canvas, getusermedia

I'm developing a monitoring system where we need to take images of our user(under their permission ofc) every x minute and the webcam HTML element wouldn't be visible to the user.

But, sometimes the snapped images are giving old images in Safari. I've created a mock app with webcamjs and I could able to reproduce this in safari only when the webcam node is hidden from the viewport.

For hiding webcam element from viewport, I've used the following style

```
#webcam{
  position: fixed;
  top: -10000px;
  left: -10000px;
}
```

## Steps to reproduce

**Specifications**

Browser: Safari version 16.0
OS: MacOS 12.6
WebcamJS: 1.0.26

- Access this [url](https://codepen.io/shiva-dev03/full/bGKdbvv) in Safari. For demo purpose, I've snapped the images every 10 seconds and rendered it into the DOM.
- You could see repeated images rendered into the DOM

## Code

```
function loadWebcamJS(){
        const webcam = document.getElementById("webcam");
        Webcam.set({
          width: 640,
          height: 480
        });
        Webcam.attach(webcam);
        Webcam.on('load', afterLoad);
      }
      const getTime = (d) =>
          `${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}:${d.getSeconds()}`;

      function snap(){
        Webcam.snap((dataURI) => {
          const results = document.getElementById('results');
          const date = new Date();
          const time = getTime(date);
          
          results.innerHTML += `
          <div class="image">
            <img src=${dataURI}
              alt="Snapped Image">
            <h4>${time}</h4>
          </div>
          
          `

        })
      }
      loadWebcamJS();
      function afterLoad(){
        
        setInterval(() => {
          snap();
        }, 1000 * 10); //Snap images every 10 seconds
        
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I'm not used to this library, so maybe they've got a cleaner way to handle this.

It seems that the autoplay fails on Safari. You can remedy this by calling yourself the `play()` method of the `<video>` that the library will append in your element.
Note that if you don't want that element to be visible in the page, you're not forced to have it in the DOM at all. I'd even advise against this since browsers do use `IntersectionObserver` instances to pause muted `<video>` elements that aren't visible. They don't pause detached `<video>` though.

So you can remove your `<div>`, and  the related CSS, and only do something like

```js
const webcam = document.createElement("div");
function loadWebcamJS() {
  Webcam.set({
    width: 640,
    height: 480
  });
  Webcam.attach(webcam);
  // force playing for Safari
  webcam.querySelector("video").play();
  Webcam.on("load", afterLoad);
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/ExRVedQ) (StackSnippets don't allow for gUM).

Comment: Does browsers pause videos that aren't visible? Is it mentioned in any doc?

Comment: I found a closed issue from webcamjs itself that, considering user safety, safari might've stopped the video feed when it is hidden. https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/issues/253

Comment: It's actually in [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#ready-states:the-video-element-4): "Optionally, when the element stops intersecting the viewport, if the can autoplay flag is still true and the autoplay attribute is still specified, run the following substeps: 1.    Run the internal pause steps and set the can autoplay flag to true." It was added in https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2324/